# Exception Code: 202 No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Structure Map Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, structuremap

Currently I've been given a WCF project which uses Structure map 2.6.1.0 for Inversion Control. Recently we have found that the service is failing occasionally with the below Error message

```
Structure map issue
Date time: 2013-11-15 05:19:58
API name: SaveJobSeekerApplicationToFocusTalent
Input data: JobSeekerId: 793576, CustomerJobId: 805299, IsApproved: True, ApprovalRequiredReason: , ApplicationScore: 927
Error response: 
Exception source: mscorlib
Exception message: StructureMap Exception Code:  202
No Default Instance defined for PluginFamily Focus.Services.ServiceContracts.ICandidateService, Focus.Services, Version=2.0.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
```

We have four services

TalentService.svc
ReportService.svc
MigrationService.svc
ImportSerice.svc

**Below is the code of TalentService**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class TalentService : InboundServiceBase, ITalentService
    {
     public TalentService()
            {
                InitialiseFocus(null, null, null, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Focus-ClientTag"));
            }


            public TalentService(IAuthenticationService authenticationService, ICandidateService candidateService, IProcessorService processorService, string clientTag)
            {
                _authenticationService = authenticationService;
                _candidateService = candidateService;
                _integrationClientTag = clientTag;
                _processorService = processorService;
            }


 protected void InitialiseFocus(IAuthenticationService authenticationService, ICandidateService candidateService, IProcessorService processorService, string clientTag)
    {
        InitialiseBootStrapper();

        lock (SyncObject)
        {
            // Setup the services
            if (_authenticationService == null)
                _authenticationService = (authenticationService ?? ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IAuthenticationService>());

            if (_candidateService == null)
                _candidateService = (candidateService ?? ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ICandidateService>());

            if (_processorService == null)
                _processorService = processorService ?? (_processorService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IProcessorService>());

            // Set up the client tag
            _integrationClientTag = clientTag;

            // Start the session with Focus Services
            _integrationSession = StartSession();

            // Authenticate the Integration User so that we get the Integration UserContext set up
            _integrationUserContext = LogIn();
        }
    }
```

}

** Code of the InboundServiceBase class **

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    [ServiceContext]
    public abstract class InboundServiceBase : ServiceBase
    {
        private static bool _bootStrapperInitialized;
        private static bool _bootMigrationStrapperInitialized;
        protected static readonly object SyncObject = new object();

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises the boot strapper.
        /// </summary>
        protected void InitialiseBootStrapper()
        {
            if (!_bootStrapperInitialized)
                lock (SyncObject)
                {
                    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "StructureMapDump.txt";
                    ServiceBootStrapper.Initialize(path);

                    _bootStrapperInitialized = true;
                }
        }

        protected void InitialiseMigrationBootStrapper()
        {
            if (!_bootMigrationStrapperInitialized)
                lock (SyncObject)
                {
                    var path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "StructureMapDump.txt";
                    MigrationServices.ServiceBootStrapper.Initialize(path);

                    _bootMigrationStrapperInitialized = true;
                }
        }
    }
```

**Code of the actual boot strapper**

```
public class ServiceBootStrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the Services.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dumpPath">The dump path.</param>
        public static void Initialize(string dumpPath)
        {
            // Initialise Structure Map
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddRegistry(new PerRequestContextRegistry<FocusUnitOfWork>("Focus"));
                x.AddRegistry(new PerRequestContextRegistry<FocusExplorerUnitOfWork>("FocusExplorer"));
                x.AddRegistry(new PerRequestContextRegistry<FocusReportingUnitOfWork>("FocusReporting"));
                x.AddRegistry(new PerRequestContextRegistry<FocusCareerUnitOfWork>("FocusCareer"));

                x.AddRegistry(new ServiceRegistry());
            });

            // Dump what we have added to Structure Map
            try
            {
                var whatDoIHave = ObjectFactory.WhatDoIHave();
                File.WriteAllText(dumpPath, whatDoIHave);
            }
            catch { }

            var coreService = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<CoreService>();
            var appSettings = coreService.AppSettings;

            // Initialise the Logger
            // Read and assign application wide logging severity
            Logger.Severity = appSettings.LogSeverity;

            // Send log / profile events to a database. 
            var application = appSettings.Application;
            var errorEmailTo = appSettings.OnErrorEmail;

            var logToDatabase = new LogToDatabase(application, "FocusLog");

            // Attach LogToEmail first so we get an email if the Db is down!
            // If LogToDatabase is first the event handler will bomb out if the 
            // Logging / Profiling Db can't be found so LogToEmail is first
            if (errorEmailTo.IsNotNullOrEmpty()) Logger.Instance.Attach(new LogToEmail(application, errorEmailTo));
            Logger.Instance.Attach(logToDatabase);

            // Initialise the Profiler
            if (appSettings.ProfilingEnabled)
                Profiler.Instance.Attach(logToDatabase);

            // Initialise the Cacher
            Cacher.Initialize(new CacheToHttpRuntime(appSettings.CachePrefix));

            // Initialise the Emailer
            if (appSettings.EmailsEnabled)
                Emailer.Instance.Attach(new EmailToSmtp());
            else
                Emailer.Instance.Attach(new EmailToFile());
        }

        #region Service Registry

        private class ServiceRegistry : Registry
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// A structure map registry for creating a Services.
            /// </summary>
            public ServiceRegistry()
            {
                // Repositories
                For<IFocusRepository>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new FocusRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<UnitOfWorkScopeBase<FocusUnitOfWork>>().Current));
                For<IFocusExplorerRepository>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new FocusExplorerRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<UnitOfWorkScopeBase<FocusExplorerUnitOfWork>>().Current));
                For<IFocusReportingRepository>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new FocusReportingRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<UnitOfWorkScopeBase<FocusReportingUnitOfWork>>().Current));
                For<IFocusCareerClientRepository>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new FocusCareerClientRepository(ObjectFactory.GetInstance<UnitOfWorkScopeBase<FocusCareerUnitOfWork>>().Current));

                // Focus Services
                For<CoreService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CoreService());
                For<ICoreService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CoreService());
                For<IAuthenticationService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new AuthenticationService());
                For<IAccountService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new AccountService());
                For<IJobService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new JobService());
                For<ISearchService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new SearchService());
                For<ICandidateService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CandidateService());
                For<IEmployerService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new EmployerService());
                For<IEmployeeService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new EmployeeService());
                For<IProfileService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ProfileService());
                For<IReportService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ReportService());
                For<IStaffService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new StaffService());
                For<IExplorerService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ExplorerService());
                For<IProcessorService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ProcessorService());
                For<IReportingService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ReportingService());
                For<IProcessIssueService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new ProcessIssueService());

                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IAccountService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.AccountService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IUtilityService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.UtilityService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IResumeService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.ResumeService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IOccupationService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.OccupationService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.ISearchService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.SearchService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IAnnotationService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.AnnotationService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IPostingService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.PostingService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IAccountOrganizerService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.AccountOrganizerService());
                For<CareerServices.ServiceContracts.IIssueService>().LifecycleIs(Lifecycles.GetLifecycle(InstanceScope.PerRequest)).Use(x => new CareerServices.ServiceImplementations.IssueService());
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

The above code works fine if a client is single threaded when a multi thread client access the service calling different services then im getting the structure map issue. I believe this is because of using the GetInstance method extensively i'm not sure if it is thread safe so i put the syncObject to sync the object instantiate process but it looks like it does not help

Please let me know what is not normal here, i'm happy to provide more info if needed